# catkin optional build dependency

Tags: ros, catkin, build, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to compile hector_quadrotor using catkin_make, but I'm running into this issue :

http://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor/issues/3

The main problem is that hector_pose_estimation uses the hector_uav_msgs package only if it is available at build time (by find_package).

But hector_pose_estimation is usable without hector_uav_msgs, so it can't be a build dependency.

And because hector_uav_msgs is not a build dep of hector_pose_estimation, catkin_make will try to build hector_pose_estimation before hector_uav_msgs.

Is there a trick to declare optional build dependencies, or to force the dependency to build hector_uav_msgs prior to hector_pose_estimation ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/83726/catkin-optional-build-dependency/) by [mtourne](https://answers.ros.org/users/7136/mtourne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-09-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no way to affect build order in a single workspace other than a `build_depend` tag. There is no notion of optional dependencies.

I imagine that `hector_pose_estimation` will publish data in messages defined in `hector_uav_msgs`, but the code to do so will only be built iff `hector_uav_msgs` is found? A different way to do this (without optional dependencies) is to have a third package which builds a plugin for `hector_pose_estimation` and directly depends on both `hector_pose_estimation` and `hector_uav_msgs`. At runtime a node in `hector_pose_estimation` could discover, load, and execute the plugin from the third package OR you could produce a node in the third package which is a drop-in replacement of the node(s) in `hector_pose_estimation` but which also publishes the messages. This way `hector_pose_estimation` is simplified and does not require an optional dependency on `hector_uav_msgs`, and to add this new functionality you just add `hector_uav_msgs` and the new third package to the workspace.

A workaround is to build `hector_uav_msgs` in a separate workspace before building `hector_pose_estimation`. This ensures that `hector_uav_msgs` is built first.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) on 2013-10-12**:
In the meantime, I did exactly this. All optional dependencies on hector_uav_msgs have been removed from hector_pose_estimation and I added a separate package hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation. Anyway, having something like optional build dependencies in package.xml would be a nice feature for catkin.